# Share same post and page data between 2 different wordpress site(different url)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have made 3 real estate demo website(with different design and layout) but due to single website hosting server I want to run all 2 demo with same database.

Comment: Sharing a database, could be difficult since the urls are set in it. 
But something like multisite should be able to do it. - read here : http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not confirm but hope this will work for you.

Install 2 website with single db ( 2 copies ).
Create new table in you'rs db. Call it **wp_options2** and copy everithing from **wp_options** inside new table
in seccond install in **wp-config.php**, before `if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ) add define( 'M7_OPTIONS_TABLE', 'wp_options2' );`
in seccond install go to wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 951 and add code:

```
if ( isset( $tables['options'] ) && defined( 'M7_OPTIONS_TABLE' ) )
                $tables['options'] = M7_OPTIONS_TABLE;
```

( these code should be added in public function tables function, before `if ( isset( $tables['users'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) ) )`

Now you should be able to change theme, plugins atc. for seccond theme, but all posts, taxonomies atc. will be dubbled in both websites ( wich is bad for seo bdw. )

if on seccond install you'll have some problems with links, add

```
define('WP_HOME','http://seccond_website.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://seccond_website.com');
```

in your wp-config.php file .....

Comment: Thanks a lot @jasbir